# Some faces are uniform, other faces are strangely 'shaded' and I can't figure out why

Tags: mesh, texturing

I rarely post asking for help; I can usually find answers by searching but this has me stumped.  Maybe I'm just not putting in the right keywords.

If you take a look at this screen shot...

[image]

You can see that some face appear perfectly uniform (with Green Dots) and some have this strange shading (The faces with Red dots).

I have checked many things:

normals all facing outwards

faces are perfectly flat

shading set to flat on all faces/verts and edges

uv's are good (though shouldn't matter in solid render view in any case)

As you can see these 'shadows' appear in the solid view but also when I'm in texture view mode.  When export the model to FBX and import into Unity the effect is still visible even then!

Any help would be gratefully received as I've spent way to long trying to figure this out.

Thanks in Advance
Ian

UPDATE:

Many thanks to all who responded to my plea.  Susu, you got me on the right track.  I just had to go into the data panel for the object and under 'Normals' just uncheck 'Auto Smooth'.  I have included an image below for any one else who may have this issue.

[image]

Thank you all again  Ian

Comment: could you please share this part of your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: clear custom normals

Comment: Please don't write the answer as part of the question. Use the answers section instead!